# Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined - react js hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm doing a useZoom component so whenever I hover an image the zoom-in will be activated but I have one issue that when I move the mouse into the image I get the error "Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined". I have initially set the value of null, but it seems that is not enough, any suggestion on how to fix this ?

[image]

```
const UseZoom = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isZoomOnSide: true,
    showOverlay: false,
    overlayLeft: 0,
    overlayTop: 0,
    zoomInLeft: 0,
    zoomInTop: 0,
    zoomInMaxWidth: 0,
  });

  let overlayNode = useRef(null);
  let imageNode = useRef(null);
  let zoomInImageNode = useRef(null);
  let zoomInWindowNode = useRef(null);


  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    // console.log("zoomInWindowNode", zoomInWindowNode.current);
    let overlayNode;
    let imageNode;
    let zoomInImageNode;
    let zoomInWindowNode;
    const zoomInWindowWidth = zoomInWindowNode.clientWidth || 1;
    const overlayWidth = overlayNode.clientWidth || 200;
    const imageWidth = imageNode.clientWidth;
    const imageHeight = imageNode.clientHeight;
    const zoomInImageWidth = zoomInImageNode.clientWidth;
    const zoomInImageHeight = zoomInImageNode.clientHeight;
    const offsetLeft = imageNode.offsetLeft;
    const offsetTop = imageNode.offsetTop;
    const overlayLeft = Math.min(
      Math.max(e.clientX - overlayWidth / 2, offsetLeft),
      offsetLeft + imageWidth - overlayWidth
    );
    const overlayTop = Math.min(
      Math.max(e.clientY - overlayWidth / 2, offsetTop),
      offsetTop + imageHeight - overlayWidth
    );
    const zoomInLeft =
      (-(overlayLeft - offsetLeft) / imageWidth) * zoomInImageWidth;
    const zoomInTop =
      (-(overlayTop - offsetTop) / imageHeight) * zoomInImageHeight;
    const zoomInMaxWidth = zoomInWindowWidth / (overlayWidth / imageWidth);
    setState({
      overlayLeft,
      overlayTop,
      zoomInLeft,
      zoomInTop,
      zoomInMaxWidth,
    });
  };

  const toggleOverlay = (showOverlay) => {
    setState({ state, showOverlay: showOverlay });
  };

  const onSwitchButtonClick = (prevState) => {
    setState({ state, isZoomOnSide: !prevState.isZoomOnSide });
  };

  const {
    showOverlay,
    overlayLeft,
    overlayTop,
    zoomInLeft,
    zoomInTop,
    zoomInMaxWidth,
    isZoomOnSide,
  } = state;

  const overlayStyle = {
    left: overlayLeft,
    top: overlayTop,
  };
  const zoomInImageStyle = {
    left: zoomInLeft,
    top: zoomInTop,
  };

  if (zoomInMaxWidth && isZoomOnSide) {
    zoomInImageStyle["max-width"] = zoomInMaxWidth;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="SwitchButton"
        type="button"
        onClick={onSwitchButtonClick}
      >
        {isZoomOnSide ? "Zoom Outside" : "Zoom Inside"}
      </button>
      <div
        className="OriginalImageContainer"
        onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
        onMouseEnter={() => toggleOverlay(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => toggleOverlay(false)}
      >
        <img
          className="OriginalImage"
          ref={imageNode}
          src="https://secure.img1-ag.wfcdn.com/im/32992506/resize-h400-w400%5Ecompr-r85/2772/27720427/Gabriel+Upholstered+Panel+Bed.jpg"
        />
        {showOverlay && isZoomOnSide && (
          <span ref={overlayNode} style={overlayStyle} />
        )}
        {showOverlay && !isZoomOnSide && (
          <div ref={zoomInWindowNode} className="ZoomInWindowInside">
            <img
              className="ZoomInWindow-Image"
              ref={zoomInImageNode}
              style={zoomInImageStyle}
              src="https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/49098658/resize-h800%5Ecompr-r85/2772/27720427/Gabriel+Upholstered+Panel+Bed.jpg"
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {showOverlay && isZoomOnSide && (
        <div ref={zoomInWindowNode} className="ZoomInWindow">
          <img
            className="ZoomInWindow-Image"
            ref={zoomInImageNode}
            style={zoomInImageStyle}
            src="https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/49098658/resize-h800%5Ecompr-r85/2772/27720427/Gabriel+Upholstered+Panel+Bed.jpg"
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UseZoom;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a `let overlayNode` and then immediately trying to access `.clientWidth` of undefined which would throw this error. You are effectively attemping `undefined.clientWidth` which throws the error "Cannot read property "X" of undefined"

Also, to access the DOM element in a `ref` you'd need to use the `ref.current` property. The ref itself is not the DOM element.

So you need to stop redeclaring the variables in your `onMouseMove` function (`let imageNode, let overlayNode` etc) as well as make sure you're checking for the correct ref property `.current`.